# Assign a name to a matrix without changing the class

Tags: r, matrix, assign, names

I am currently working on a for-loop, which looks like this:

```
for(i in 1) { 
nam <- paste(Test[i,1])
assign(nam, matrix(nrow=1,ncol=8))}

(Test is a vector with random entries and I want to use the first as a name)
```

The problem I have with this, is that once I use assign the class of the matrix is changed from class to logi. How can I rename the Matrix in the environment and still have a matrix class?

Answer (score 0):

The function `matrix(nrow=1,ncol=8)` creates a new empty 1x8 matrix. Since it is initialized empty, it assumes the simplest case for the *elements* of the matrix, which is class `logical`. The matrix assigned to the name stored in `nam` is indeed still a matrix, it is only the elements of that matrix which are class `logical`.

```
> nam <- 'myname'
> assign(nam, matrix(nrow=1,ncol=8))
> class(myname)
[1] "matrix"
> class(myname[1, 1])
[1] "logical"
```

By the way, a couple things about this example appear odd, one assumes that in your actual use they make more sense - looping over only `1`, for example, or using `paste()` on a single element.